# How to set line length limit when using grep (Filter result by line length)?

Tags: linux, unix, regex, grep

The use case is that I am searching for a particular CSS attribute in a directory of HTML/CSS/JS files (including sub-directories). Some one-liner JS libraries also have the CSS attribute that I'm searching for.

So is there a way to tell grep that it should not give result on a line which is longer than my defined `$max_line_length`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First approach, try to exclude the one-liner JS files from being grepped in the first place.
Often these will have a name like some-library.min.js, so you could do something like:

```
$ grep --exclude '*.min.js' ...
```

Another approach is that if you know that it's going to be in a CSS file, you can use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to restrict your search to CSS files (and ignore various VCS cruft):

```
$ ack --type=css ...
```

However, to answer your question, you can write a regular expression to match on line length. The following will match any line with 100 or fewer characters.

```
$ grep -E '^.{,100}$'
```

Comment: +1 `ack-grep` on some systems

Comment: Also, ack will ignore minified Javascript files.  It sees them as not being source code, and so ignores.

Comment: My grep only worked with {0,100} for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to pipe through **cut** to cut the lines amd invert match -v to exclude stuff. Better readable to me. I guess perfomance wise not optimal

```
grep -r something . | cut -b 1-99 | grep -v min.js
```

Comment: They don't want to cut the lines, they want exclude lines longer than `$max_line_length`